# Prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int\limits_0^1 \sin(x^n)dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Prove $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int\limits_0^1 \sin(x^n)dx=0$$

I found that $\sin(x^n)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)=0$ on $[0, a]$ for every $0<a<1$.

Therefore I know that for every $0<a<1$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int\limits_0^a \sin(x^n)dx = \int\limits_0^a 0dx=0$

But how do I show it is true for $\int_0^1$?

I know there are some advanced techniques which allow swapping the order of limits which could solve this but most of them I probably did not study yet, so if you use such techniques please specify. Most basic solution would be best.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not need any convergence theorem. Just use triangle inequality and the fact that $|\sin(t)|\leq |t|$ to obtain the inequalities $0\leq\left|\int_0^1\sin\left(x^n\right)\space\text{d}x\right|\leq\int_0^1x^n\space\text{d}x$.The integral on the right yields $\frac{1}{n+1}$. Now take $n\to \infty$ and squeeze.

Comment: +1 Nice answer.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar Well, done!

Comment: @Jan I'm sorry I don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $|\int_0^{\epsilon} \sin (x^{n}) dx| \leq \int_0^{\epsilon} dx=\epsilon$ and $\int_{\epsilon}^{1} \sin (x^{n}) dx \to 0$ by uniform convergence. Put these two together.